# How to Upload File to Firebase Storage in .Net C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, firebase, firebase-storage

I Tried the Following Function to upload an image to Firebase Storage

```
 private async void UploadFiles()
    {

        var stream = File.Open(@"D:\\Capture.png", FileMode.Open);
        var auth = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(ApiKey));
        var a = await auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(AuthEmail, AuthPassword);

        var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = new FirebaseStorage(
            Bucket,
            new FirebaseStorageOptions
            {
                AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(a.FirebaseToken),
                ThrowOnCancel = true // when you cancel the upload, exception is thrown. By default no exception is thrown
            })
            .Child("receipts")
           // .Child("test")
            .Child("Capture.png")
            .PutAsync(stream, cancellation.Token);
        task.Progress.ProgressChanged += (s, e) => textBox1 .Text =($"Progress: {e.Percentage} %");

        // cancel the upload
        // cancellation.Cancel();

        try
        {
            // error during upload will be thrown when you await the task
          textBox1 .Text =("Download link:\n" + await task);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox .Show( ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Get me this error :

> Exception occured while processing the request.
>   Url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gs://testingsupport-44f0b.appspot.com//o?name=receipts%2FCapture.png
>   Response: {
>     "error": {
>       "code": 400,
>       "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
>     }
>   }

Comment: in the above code i am using Firebase Storage.net :https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-storage-dotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit your `Bucket` variable. Instead of using `gs://xxxxx.appspot.com/` it should be only `xxxxx.appspot.com`

Comment: Nice to know that it solved your issue! Could you mark the answer as a solution?

Comment: Any idea how to 'peek' or 'read' a file that is already on Storage?