# Firebase Storage read or query existing data with .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, visual-studio, firebase-storage

Environment: VS project, .NET, C#

I've implemented uploading documents to my **Firebase Storage** `Bucket` via the example in the link below:

[How to Upload File to Firebase Storage in .Net C# Windows Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54486640/how-to-upload-file-to-firebase-storage-in-net-c-sharp-windows-form)

I'm trying to find documentation on how to use the same library/functionality to read a file that I've manually uploaded to my `Bucket`.

In essence: how to 'peek' or 'read' a file that is **already** on Storage? I basically want to query data inside an existing **csv** file.

So far I've found documentation only here, which doesn't provide much in terms of a possible solution, at least as far as I can understand it...
[Firebase Storage Introduction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage)

There is seemingly more related information on the same page on the 'Firebase Store' section, but that isn't the same as Firebase Storage :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/latest), It seems you can open files by downloading them.

```cs
var client = StorageClient.Create();

// Create a bucket with a globally unique name
var bucketName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var bucket = client.CreateBucket(projectId, bucketName);

// Upload some files
var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello, world");
var obj1 = client.UploadObject(bucketName, "file1.txt", "text/plain", new MemoryStream(content));
var obj2 = client.UploadObject(bucketName, "folder1/file2.txt", "text/plain", new MemoryStream(content));

// List objects
foreach (var obj in client.ListObjects(bucketName, ""))
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
}

// Download file
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("file1.txt"))
{
    client.DownloadObject(bucketName, "file1.txt", stream);
}
```